# How to integrate iOS application (module) in a existing React Native app ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mobile, react-native

I have an existing iOS application (containing a Main Storyboard, ViewController and 2 classes for managing video recording). I want to integrate it in a React Native project. I don't know how to integrate the ViewController and the Main.Storyboard. How can I make the bridge between my ViewController and Main.Storyboard with my React Native project? Thanks